# Firebase database and Ionic

Tags: database, firebase, ionic-framework, mobile

I'm going to start developing an application using Ionic and I have a question, I need the user to be able to use the offiline system and if you want to create an account and synchronize the data in the cloud. The application does not search anything from the network, the user will be responsible for entering the data. I saw that Firebase does the automatic synchronization, but the question is, is it only able to offer a local bank offiline and if the user wants, can send this data to the cloud?

Comment: You should check https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/ - Firebase Firestore has what you need potentially. And yes you can organize the logic the way you described. Try starting your implementation an then if you get stuck ask specific question here at SO.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko As far as I know Firestore currently doesn't have an API to control whether it synchronizes local writes to the server. From what I can tell that would be a requirement for Bruno's use-case

Comment: Oh so its sort of "always on"?

Comment: I'm developing with Firebase, if don't work, I apply another idea that I have. Thanks!